# How to add android studio Offline components

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I dont know how to install it offline and set Android studio for new version 3.6.1 to use the offline version. I need help. also I am a beginner

Comment: Are you using windows or mac?

Comment: @Tomas Mota windows 8

Comment: Go to File->Settings-> Build, Excute and Deployment-> Gradle and turn the "offline" box on